# AWS DynamoDB - How to use FilterExpression?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have two `dynamodb` tables, one called Users and another called Parking.

Parking schema :

```
{
   'id' : 'test',
    'admins' : [USER_SCHEMA]

}
```

Users schema :

```
{
  'user_ID' : 'test',
  'fullname' : 'test'
}
```

Parking schema contains an array of admins (users object), what I need to do is to make a query that will take `user_ID` from `event.body` in the Lambda function and then scan the `parking` table in order to get all the parking items in which the `admins` array has a user object matches the `user_ID`.

How can I achieve this with `FitlerExpression` in dynamodb please ? And if `FilterExpression` is not the right way to go with, then how can I possibly do this ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You need to rethink your data model, you should not need to ever scan the dynamodb. And using a FilterExpression is already a smell because it gives the appearance of performing a proper `select ... where ...` but actually you run a `select *` and then filter in the client, just that the client doing the filtering is the dynamodb api but you still pay for the `select *`.

Comment: Do you propose removing the array from the schema and replace it with `user_ID` directly as a string sir ?